How to use argmax in Bayesian posterior estimate?
I have some yield function $f_\beta(x)$. I want to find the value $x$ that maximizes the yield. However, my function is parameterized by a parameter $\beta$. For simplicity let's assume there is only one parameter, and that it is discrete. Let's also assume that I have managed to estimate a Bayesian posterior probability over $\beta$.
What is the correct way to estimate the value of $x$ that maximizes the expected yield? I can see two options.
Option 1
$
\begin{align}
\text{optimum} &= \text{argmax}_x(\mathbb{E}(f_{\beta}(x))) \\
               &= \text{argmax}_x(\sum_{\beta} P(\beta) * f_{\beta}(x)) \\
\end{align}
$
Option 2
$
\begin{align}
\text{optimum} &= \sum_{\beta} P(\beta) * \text{argmax}_x(f_{\beta}(x))
\end{align}
$
Which is the correct way to do correct Bayesian posterior inference to get the optimum? Please explain why this is the correct way. Or perhaps give an example to make it intuitively clear why this option is the correct one.

In the second case, since you are maximizing each $f_\beta(x)$ first, you may get different optimal $x_\beta^{\text{opt}}$, dependent on $\beta$, for each $f_\beta(x)$. That doesn't seem to be what you want, you just want a single $x^\text{opt}$, independent of the $\beta$, that maximizes the whole problem.

Yes, but as you can see in option 2 I'm still averaging out over them, leading to one final optimum.

Averaging a collection of separately optimal $x_\beta$'s will almost never give you an overall maximizer. Say $\beta \in {+1, -1}$ with equal probability; say $f_\beta(x)$ takes a maximum at $x_\beta^\ast = \beta$ and a minimum at $0$. Then your option 2 gives a supposedly "optimal maximizer" $x^\ast = \frac{1}{2}(1  - 1) = 0$ which doesn't maximize at all; in fact minimizes both your $f_\beta(x)$!

Your option 1 using a probability-weighted average of the yields looks as if it "maximizes the expected yield" and so is what you asked for.
Your option 2 using a probability-weighted average of the optimal $x$s may not even be a possible $x$, especially if $x$ only takes discrete values.  I am not sure this can be described as optimal in any sense.  The calculated $x$ may have have very low or no expected yield.
There may be another option giving a different $x$, aiming at maximising the likelihood of achieving the maximum yield (a sort of mode of possible modes): in some cases this might be $\underset{x}{\operatorname{argmax}}\big(f_{\hat \beta}(x)\big)$ where $\hat\beta=\underset{\beta}{\operatorname{argmax}}\big(P(\beta)\big)$ when different $\beta$s give different $\underset{x}{\operatorname{argmax}}\big(f_{\beta}(x)\big)$; otherwise you may need to find which of the possible optimal $x$s has the highest combined posterior likelihood over the $\beta$s of being optimal.
